# Oracle Apex 19 - Dynamically change page item template

Tags: oracle-apex

Is there a simple way to dynamically change the page item template, that can be found in the Appearance tab?

For example, if a page item has a certain value, the template for another item should switch from Optional to Required. I could create two items, but is there a better solution?

Comment: Is this what you're chasing? https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2014/01/change-an-item-label-dynamically/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Universal Theme then each item will be within a "container" div with an ID of `<item_name>_CONTAINER` - for example, item `P101_EMPNO` will have a container div called `P101_EMPNO_CONTAINER`.  This container div will have a class `is-required` if the item has a "required" template but not if it has an "optional" template.

So, all you need to do in a dynamic action is use a little Javascript:

1. When item becomes required:

```
    $('#P101_EMPNO_CONTAINER').addClass('is-required');
```

2. When item becomes optional:

```
    $('#P101_EMPNO_CONTAINER').removeClass('is-required');
```

If you needed to do this in a few places you could simplify the process and protect yourself from future changes to the Universal Theme by creating Javascript library functions that you would call using the item name, for example:

```
    mylib.makeRequired('P101_EMPNO');
```

```
    mylib.makeOptional('P101_EMPNO');
```